# Pgfplot barplot with cluster of stackedbars

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I create a pgfplot that have two stacked ybar for each "point in x axis" ?

I wan't something like this:

[image]

I already have a graph that have one stacked bar for each x point. Some hint on how to extend it or a link for an example will be sufficient.

Comment: I have been wrong before but I think this is not possible as the axis is prepared for either `ybar` or the `ybar stacked`. It seems like feature request for a possible mixture of the styles. You can try to place an empty axis on top and shift the bars of the second axis but still it would be a tedious hack.

Comment: Related: [pgfplots: Multiple (shifted) stacked plots in one diagram](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13627/pgfplots-multiple-shifted-stacked-plots-in-one-diagram)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to try, but I think in the end I agree with **percusse**: It's a littletedious. You can use two `axis` and use the (so far quite convineant) `bar shift=<lenth>` option, however, depending on the width of the picture, you'll have to experiment a little. Furthermore, you have to use the `ymin=<number>` and `ymax=<number>` as otherwise the y-axes won't align properly. Here's an example to illustrate it cane be done with a little hassle:

### Code

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar stacked,bar shift=7pt,ymin=0,ymax=11,symbolic x coords={A,B,C,D,E}]]  
\addplot coordinates
{(A,1) (B,1) (C,3) (D,2) (E,1.5)};
\addplot coordinates
{(A,1) (B,1) (C,3) (D,2) (E,1.5)};
\addplot coordinates
{(A,1) (B,1) (C,3) (D,2) (E,1.5)};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[ybar stacked,bar shift=-7pt,ymin=0,ymax=11,symbolic x coords={A,B,C,D,E}]  
\addplot+[fill=blue!50!gray] coordinates
{(A,1.5) (B,1.5) (C,3.5) (D,2.5) (E,1)};
\addplot+[fill=red!50!gray] coordinates
{(A,1.5) (B,1.5) (C,3.5) (D,2.5) (E,1)};
\addplot+[fill=yellow!50!gray] coordinates
{(A,1.5) (B,1.5) (C,3.5) (D,2.5) (E,1)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: very good. Its exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @JohnTortugo if Tom has solved the problem, you can reward him by accepting his answer using the green check mark- this will give him 15 well-earned reputation points :)