# How to shift x ticks in pgfplots having multiple stacked bars

Tags: pgfplots

My goal is to generate this bar chart:

[image]

I was able to achieve this chart as my MWE:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.6}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/flexible xticklabels from table/.code n args={3}{%
        \pgfplotstableread[#3]{#1}\coordinate@table
        \pgfplotstablegetcolumn{#2}\of{\coordinate@table}\to\pgfplots@xticklabels
        \let\pgfplots@xticklabel=\pgfplots@user@ticklabel@list@x
    }
}
\makeatother

% argument #1: any options
\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    % inits/clears the lists (which might be populated from previous
    % axes):
    \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    % draws the legend:
    \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
    \endgroup
}%

% makes \addlegendimage available (typically only available within an
% axis environment):
\def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.csv}
matrix   P   methodAfirstPhase   methodAsecondPhase methodBfirstPhase   methodBsecondPhase
a    2   3   7   2  5
a    4   1   4   1  3
b    2   2   6   1  5
b    4   1   2   1  1   
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\def\numpsPLOT{2}
\def\nummtx{2}

\foreach \matrixid/\P/\axisState/\barShift/\Pshift in {0/2//0/0, 0/4/hide axis/30/.1, 1/2/hide axis/70/.3, 1/4/hide axis/100/.4} {
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0}%
\pgfmathparse{\matrixid*\numpsPLOT-1}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\le{\pgfmathresult+1}%
\pgfmathparse{\matrixid*\numpsPLOT+\numpsPLOT}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\us{\pgfmathresult}%
\pgfmathparse{\nummtx*\numpsPLOT}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\ue{\pgfmathresult}%

\begin{axis}
[   ybar stacked,
\axisState,
bar shift=\barShift-100,
enlarge x limits=9,
ymin=0,ymax=11,
x filter/.code={\expandafter\ifnum \thisrow{P}=\P\else\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi},
flexible xticklabels from table={testdata.csv}{matrix}{}, %ignore chars={\%,\_}
x tick label style={font=\small,text width=1.7cm,align=center,rotate=45},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords*,
]  
\addplot[black,fill=black!20] table
[   x expr=\coordindex,
    y=methodAfirstPhase,
   skip coords between index={-1}{\le},  skip coords between index={\us}{\ue}
] {testdata.csv};
\addplot[black,pattern=north west lines,] table
[  x expr=\coordindex,
    y=methodAsecondPhase,
   skip coords between index={-1}{\le},  skip coords between index={\us}{\ue}
] {testdata.csv};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}
[   ybar stacked,
\axisState,
bar shift={\barShift+10-100},
enlarge x limits=9,
ymin=0,ymax=11,
x filter/.code={\expandafter\ifnum \thisrow{P}=\P\else\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi},
flexible xticklabels from table={testdata.csv}{matrix}{}, %ignore chars={\%,\_}
x tick label style={font=\small,text width=1.7cm,align=center,rotate=45},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords*,
]  
\addplot[black,fill=black!40] table
[   x expr=\coordindex,
    y=methodBfirstPhase,
    skip coords between index={-1}{\le},  skip coords between index={\us}{\ue}
] {testdata.csv};
\addplot[black,fill=black!40,pattern=north east lines,] table
[   x expr=\coordindex,
    y=methodBsecondPhase,
   skip coords between index={-1}{\le},  skip coords between index={\us}{\ue}
] {testdata.csv};
\end{axis}
\node[below left] at (rel axis cs:0.65+\Pshift,1) {P=\P};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{customlegend}[legend columns=2,legend style={align=left,draw=none,column sep=2ex},legend entries={Method A $\Phi1$,Method B $\Phi1$,Method A $\Phi2$,Method B $\Phi2$}]
    \addlegendimage{black,fill=black!20,area legend}
    \addlegendimage{black,fill=black!40,area legend}   
    \addlegendimage{black,fill=black!50,area legend,pattern=north west lines,}
    \addlegendimage{black,fill=black!0,area legend,pattern=north east lines,}
    \end{customlegend}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Outcome:

[image]

Here what I want:

[image]

There are three problems:

1) I want names of matrices to be put below related bars. I cannot use `symbolic x coords={a,b}` since matrix names must be loaded from data file. In my MWE, only matrix name `a` is visible, but `b` is missing. I shift bars via `bar shift=...` but I cannot shift x ticks. Is there any way to shift x ticks?

2) I cannot put numbers inside the bars. Matrix names and numbers must be shifted as the bar shifted via `bar shift=...`. ([Same problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13627/pgfplots-multiple-shifted-stacked-plots-in-one-diagram#comment144606_13665)) Again note that I cannot use `symbolic x coords={a,b}` since matrix names are determined dynamically according to data file.

3) I want to put processor numbers according to bars and just above or preferably below the corresponding bar. In my MWE, I have put processor numbers manually. I want to automatically put according to related bar.

In my original code; number of processors, matrix names, number of matrices, ... everything may change so my code should be flexible.

Comment: Can you  cook up something in excel or scribble on to a paper to describe the expected outcome better? It is kind of difficult to get what you are after.

Comment: Dear @percusse, thanks for this comment. From now on, I will try to include sample outcomes that I expect. For this question, I have included link of a sample bar chart that I need.

Comment: Is [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70731/pgfplot-histogram-with-stackedbars/70764#70764) what you're looking for?

Comment: Dear @TomBombadil, thanks for the link and solution. My second problem was asked in that link.

Comment: Dear @percusse, thanks for the image, you saved us from an indirection :-)

Comment: @Kadir Ne demek, my pleasure :)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you want with 1) and 3). Could you probably explain in more detail, and probably provide a mock up, e.g. draw the info you need into the image with Gimp or something. For the second problem, I'll update my post in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added additional fields to determine places of bars and an empty axis to add x ticks. Note that these additional fields can be generated automatically via preprocessing the table in the question via using `pgfplotstable`.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.6}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/flexible xticklabels from table/.code n args={3}{%
        \pgfplotstableread[#3]{#1}\coordinate@table
        \pgfplotstablegetcolumn{#2}\of{\coordinate@table}\to\pgfplots@xticklabels
        \let\pgfplots@xticklabel=\pgfplots@user@ticklabel@list@x
    }
}
\makeatother

% argument #1: any options
\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    % inits/clears the lists (which might be populated from previous
    % axes):
    \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    % draws the legend:
    \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
    \endgroup
}%

% makes \addlegendimage available (typically only available within an
% axis environment):
\def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.csv}
id    idb   matrix   P   methodAfirstPhase   methodAsecondPhase methodBfirstPhase   methodBsecondPhase
0      .5   a    2   3   7   2  5
1.5    2    a    4   1   4   1  3
3.5    4    b    2   2   6   1  5
5    5.5    b    4   1   2   1  1   
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{matrixnames.csv}
matrix xval yval
a           1.5      0
b           4.5     0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [remember picture]
\def\numpsPLOT{2}
\def\nummtx{2}

\begin{axis}[ybar,
xticklabels from table={matrixnames.csv}{matrix},
xtick=data,ymin=0,ymax=11,xmin=0,xmax=10,]
\addplot table 
[  x=xval,
   y=yval
 ]{matrixnames.csv};
\end{axis}

\foreach \matrixid/\P/\axisState/\barShift/\Pshift in {0/2/hide axis/0/0, 0/4/hide axis/30/.1, 1/2/hide axis/70/.3, 1/4/hide axis/100/.4} {
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0}%
\pgfmathparse{\matrixid*\numpsPLOT-1}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\le{\pgfmathresult+1}%
\pgfmathparse{\matrixid*\numpsPLOT+\numpsPLOT}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\us{\pgfmathresult}%
\pgfmathparse{\nummtx*\numpsPLOT}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\ue{\pgfmathresult}%

\begin{axis}
[   ybar stacked,
    \axisState,
    enlarge x limits,
    ymin=0,ymax=11,
    x filter/.code={\expandafter\ifnum \thisrow{P}=\P\else\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi},
    nodes near coords*,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=10,
]  
\addplot[black,fill=black!20] table
[  % x expr=\coordindex,
x=id,
    y=methodAfirstPhase,
   skip coords between index={-1}{\le},  skip coords between index={\us}{\ue}
] {testdata.csv};
\addplot[black,pattern=north west lines,] table
[  x=id,
    y=methodAsecondPhase,
   skip coords between index={-1}{\le},  skip coords between index={\us}{\ue},
] {testdata.csv};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}
[   ybar stacked,
    \axisState,
    enlarge x limits,
    ymin=0,ymax=11,
    x filter/.code={\expandafter\ifnum \thisrow{P}=\P\else\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi},
    xtick=data,
   nodes near coords*,
   xmin=0,
   xmax=10,
]  
\addplot[black,fill=black!40] table
[   x=idb,
    y=methodBfirstPhase,
    skip coords between index={-1}{\le},  skip coords between index={\us}{\ue}
] {testdata.csv};
\addplot[black,fill=black!40,pattern=north east lines,] table
[  x=idb,
    y=methodBsecondPhase,
   skip coords between index={-1}{\le},  skip coords between index={\us}{\ue}
] {testdata.csv};
\end{axis}
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{customlegend}[legend columns=2,legend style={align=left,draw=none,column sep=2ex},legend entries={Method A $\Phi1$,Method B $\Phi1$,Method A $\Phi2$,Method B $\Phi2$}]
    \addlegendimage{black,fill=black!20,area legend}
    \addlegendimage{black,fill=black!40,area legend}   
    \addlegendimage{black,fill=black!50,area legend,pattern=north west lines,}
    \addlegendimage{black,fill=black!0,area legend,pattern=north east lines,}
    \end{customlegend}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how well you can adapt this to your scenario, the solution is not that elegant. In order to have one legend for all four axes, it uses **Christian Feuersänger**'s solution to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54834/7279).

### Code

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.6}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\usepackage{filecontents}

% argument #1: any options
\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    % inits/clears the lists (which might be populated from previous
    % axes):
    \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    % draws the legend:
    \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
    \endgroup
}%

% makes \addlegendimage available (typically only available within an
% axis environment):
\def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.csv}
matrix   P   methodAfirstPhase   methodAsecondPhase methodBfirstPhase   methodBsecondPhase
a    2   3   7   2  6
a    4   1   4   1  3
b    2   2   6   1  5
b    4   1   2   1  1   
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\begin{axis}
[   ybar stacked,
    bar shift=-20pt,
    ymin=0,ymax=11,
    symbolic x coords={a,b},
    x filter/.code={\expandafter\ifnum \thisrow{P}=4 \def\pgfmathresult{}\fi},
    xtick={a,b},
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
    grid=major,
]  
    \addplot[black,fill=black!20] table
    [   x=matrix,
        y=methodAfirstPhase,
    ] {testdata.csv};
    \addplot[black,fill=black!0] table
    [   x=matrix,
        y=methodAsecondPhase,
    ] {testdata.csv};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}
[   ybar stacked,
    bar shift=-8pt,
    ymin=0,ymax=11,
    symbolic x coords={a,b},
    x filter/.code={\expandafter\ifnum \thisrow{P}=2 \def\pgfmathresult{}\fi},
    hide axis,
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
]  
    \addplot[black,fill=black!70] table
    [   x=matrix,
        y=methodBfirstPhase,
    ] {testdata.csv};
    \addplot[black,fill=black!50] table
    [   x=matrix,
        y=methodBsecondPhase,
    ] {testdata.csv};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}
[   ybar stacked,
    bar shift=8pt,
    ymin=0,ymax=11,
    symbolic x coords={a,b},
    x filter/.code={\expandafter\ifnum \thisrow{P}=2 \def\pgfmathresult{}\fi},
    hide axis,
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
]  
    \addplot[black,fill=black!20] table
    [   x=matrix,
        y=methodAfirstPhase,
    ] {testdata.csv};
    \addplot[black,fill=black!0] table
    [   x=matrix,
        y=methodAsecondPhase,
    ] {testdata.csv};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}
[   ybar stacked,
    bar shift=20pt,
    ymin=0,ymax=11,
    symbolic x coords={a,b},
    x filter/.code={\expandafter\ifnum \thisrow{P}=2 \def\pgfmathresult{}\fi},
    hide axis,
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
]  
    \addplot[black,fill=black!70] table
    [   x=matrix,
        y=methodBfirstPhase,
    ] {testdata.csv};
    \addplot[black,fill=black!50] table
    [   x=matrix,
        y=methodBsecondPhase,
    ] {testdata.csv};
    \node[below left] at (rel axis cs:0.25,1) {P=2};
    \node[below right] at (rel axis cs:0.25,1) {P=4};
    \node[below left] at (rel axis cs:0.75,1) {P=2};
    \node[below right] at (rel axis cs:0.75,1) {P=4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{customlegend}[legend entries={Method A (First Phase),Method B (First Phase),Method A (Second Phase),Method B (Second Phase)}]
    \addlegendimage{black,fill=black!70,area legend}
    \addlegendimage{black,fill=black!20,area legend}
    \addlegendimage{black,fill=black!50,area legend}
    \addlegendimage{black,fill=black!0,area legend}
    \end{customlegend}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** To put numbers in the bars, you can use `point meta={rawy}`:

### Code

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.6}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\usepackage{filecontents}

% argument #1: any options
\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    % inits/clears the lists (which might be populated from previous
    % axes):
    \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    % draws the legend:
    \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
    \endgroup
}%

% makes \addlegendimage available (typically only available within an
% axis environment):
\def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.csv}
matrix   P   methodAfirstPhase   methodAsecondPhase methodBfirstPhase   methodBsecondPhase
a    2   3   7   2  6
a    4   1   4   1  3
b    2   2   6   1  5
b    4   1   2   1  1   
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\begin{axis}
[   ybar stacked,
    bar shift=-20pt,
    ymin=0,ymax=11,
    symbolic x coords={a,b},
    x filter/.code={\expandafter\ifnum \thisrow{P}=4 \def\pgfmathresult{}\fi},
    xtick={a,b},
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
    grid=major,
    every node near coord/.append style={anchor=north,xshift=-20pt,font=\tiny},
    nodes near coords,
]  
    \addplot[black,fill=black!20] table
    [   x=matrix,
        y=methodAfirstPhase,
    ] {testdata.csv};
    \addplot[black,fill=black!0] table
    [   x=matrix,
        y=methodAsecondPhase,
        point meta={rawy},
    ] {testdata.csv};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}
[   ybar stacked,
    bar shift=-8pt,
    ymin=0,ymax=11,
    symbolic x coords={a,b},
    x filter/.code={\expandafter\ifnum \thisrow{P}=2 \def\pgfmathresult{}\fi},
    hide axis,
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
    every node near coord/.append style={anchor=north,xshift=-8pt,font=\tiny},
    nodes near coords,
]  
    \addplot[black,fill=black!70] table
    [   x=matrix,
        y=methodBfirstPhase,
    ] {testdata.csv};
    \addplot[black,fill=black!50] table
    [   x=matrix,
        y=methodBsecondPhase,
        point meta={rawy},
    ] {testdata.csv};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}
[   ybar stacked,
    bar shift=8pt,
    ymin=0,ymax=11,
    symbolic x coords={a,b},
    x filter/.code={\expandafter\ifnum \thisrow{P}=2 \def\pgfmathresult{}\fi},
    hide axis,
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
        every node near coord/.append style={anchor=north,xshift=8pt,font=\tiny},
    nodes near coords,
]  
    \addplot[black,fill=black!20] table
    [   x=matrix,
        y=methodAfirstPhase,
    ] {testdata.csv};
    \addplot[black,fill=black!0] table
    [   x=matrix,
        y=methodAsecondPhase,
        point meta={rawy},
    ] {testdata.csv};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}
[   ybar stacked,
    bar shift=20pt,
    ymin=0,ymax=11,
    symbolic x coords={a,b},
    x filter/.code={\expandafter\ifnum \thisrow{P}=2 \def\pgfmathresult{}\fi},
    hide axis,
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
    every node near coord/.append style={anchor=north,xshift=20pt,font=\tiny},
    nodes near coords,
]  
    \addplot[black,fill=black!70] table
    [   x=matrix,
        y=methodBfirstPhase,
    ] {testdata.csv};
    \addplot[black,fill=black!50] table
    [   x=matrix,
        y=methodBsecondPhase,
        point meta={rawy},
    ] {testdata.csv};
    \node[below left] at (rel axis cs:0.25,1) {P=2};
    \node[below right] at (rel axis cs:0.25,1) {P=4};
    \node[below left] at (rel axis cs:0.75,1) {P=2};
    \node[below right] at (rel axis cs:0.75,1) {P=4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{customlegend}[legend entries={Method A (First Phase),Method B (First Phase),Method A (Second Phase),Method B (Second Phase)}]
    \addlegendimage{black,fill=black!70,area legend}
    \addlegendimage{black,fill=black!20,area legend}
    \addlegendimage{black,fill=black!50,area legend}
    \addlegendimage{black,fill=black!0,area legend}
    \end{customlegend}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Dear @TomBombadil, thanks for your solution. I have improved my MWE according to your solution. However, I have encountered three problems as indicated in the updated question.

Comment: Dear @TomBombadil, thanks for your *Edit 1*. It works in your case -- when `symbolic x coords={a,b}` is used. However, I cannot use `symbolic x coords={a,b}` since matrix names must be dynamically loaded from data file as I do in my MWE (this is taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63335/pgfplots-using-strings-from-data-table-as-x-axis-labels-in-bar-chart).