# Alternating colors for stacked bar charts

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to make a stacked bar chart with two bars next to each other with different colors. I've based my code on discarding `\addplot` commands similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-a-single-bar-when-the-bar-plot-is-based-on), but even though I'm discarding an `\addplot` it seems to remember the height of the previous bar (due to stacking presumably). I want all bars to start at `y=0`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{
    discard if/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    },
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
X   Alpha   Name    Normal  Spike   Min     Max
1   5       CR      2.42    3.19    0.92    0.98
2   5       LR      2.48    0.80    0.59    0.47
4   10      CR      2.03    3.30    1.76    2.21
5   10      LR      2.10    0.92    0.53    0.62
7   15      CR      2.03    2.88    1.60    1.28
8   15      LR      2.05    1.12    0.68    0.69
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{data.csv}
\edef\numberofrows{\pgfplotsretval}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=10cm,height=6cm,
    ybar stacked,
    xtick={1,2,4,5,7,8},
    xticklabels from table={data.csv}{X},
]

\addplot [draw,fill=orange,discard if={Name}{LR}] table [x=X, y=Normal] {data.csv};
\addplot [draw,fill=orange!20,discard if={Name}{LR}] table [x=X, y=Spike] {data.csv};

\addplot [draw,fill=green,discard if={Name}{CR}] table [x=X, y=Normal] {data.csv};
\addplot [draw,fill=green!20,discard if={Name}{CR}] table [x=X, y=Spike] {data.csv};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13627/pgfplots-multiple-shifted-stacked-plots-in-one-diagram) helped to solve my problem.