# Pgfplots: Stacked Bar Plot distorted if second plot is added

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I am trying to create a stacked bar plot in oder to compare two sets of data. If I add only one plot (in this example just uncomment the other plot) everything looks perfect, but if i try to activate both at the same time, curious things happen. Can sombody please help?
Please excuse the poor layout in the example, in reality I read from a data file with more entries and the plot looks nicer. 
Working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xbar stacked,
symbolic y coords={DP,DPn},
bar width=7pt,
y=0.8cm]

\addplot coordinates {(10.322289,DP) (5.856952215,DP) (1.0252891,DP)};
\addplot coordinates {(10.26813236,DPn) (5.833599714,DPn) (1.035041566,DPn)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Picture of the whole plot (the working example only includes the first entry but shows the same issue).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did my answer answer your question? If yes, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) it and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). If not, please edit your question again and state what you are missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply use it wrong. Each `\addplot` command should contain only *one* coordinate per `ytick` and they get stacked by multiple of such `\addplot` commands. So a simple rearrangement of your coordinates to different `\addplot` commands solves your problem.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar stacked,
        symbolic y coords={DP,DPn},
        ytick=data,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(10.322289,DP) (10.26813236,DPn)};
        \addplot coordinates {(5.856952215,DP) (5.833599714,DPn)};
        \addplot coordinates {(1.0252891,DP) (1.035041566,DPn)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: thank you this was very useful! now i adapted my data, but my problem is, that i am comparing data for each point, so i want every first bar to be red and every second bar to be blue for example. is there a possibility to mix up two stacked bar plots? or change the color for each point added?  (i added a picture to explain to the original post)

Answer (score 0):

okay, i did find my own solution, based on this thread: 
[pgfplots: Multiple (shifted) stacked plots in one diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13627/pgfplots-multiple-shifted-stacked-plots-in-one-diagram)
now i adjusted the colours and could get the plot i wanted:[image]